# High downvote to upvote ratio (not serial downvoting)

Tags: discussion, voting

Often times I've found that questions and answers that deserve a downvote elicit a heavier emotional response than upvotes. It's easier to recognize a bad question/answer than a good answer, and even then, upvoting is just an after thought. In particular, I'm worried that having a high downvote to upvote ratio is considered serial downvoting or frowned upon by the community. Unlike mass upvoting which is countered by a reputation cap and can be done with impunity, downvoting is discouraged by costing one reputation.

However, I'm not aware of any negative consequences to mass downvoting (as long as it isn't serial downvoting) aside from losing a lot of reputation, so is it okay to do so?

Pros:

- Those that don't care about reputation can exercise their right to vote without overly restrictive limitations.
- Questions and answers that deserve to be downvoted will be - considering I've seen people either not vote, or just upvote.

Cons:

- Loss of reputation.
- Angry response from people wondering why they're being downvoted - but this kind of counteracts the point of anonymity.

Comment: Downvotes on *answers* cost rep.  Downvotes on questions do not.

Comment: Do you really *care* if someone else would have a problem with you voting on posts based on what you think their usefulness is?  Would you actually not vote as you think a post deserves just because others think that you downvote more than you should?

Comment: High downvote to upvote ratio just means that you've been helping to clean up the crap.

Comment: I personally have a [slightly high](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedron) downvote to upvote ratio and I'm proud about it. It shows that I rate content and moderate bad ones pretty actively - Most of the times by downvoting bad content, I post a follow-up comment and the author retracts their post or improves it. There's __nothing wrong__ with having a ratio.

Comment: unfortunately there are more bad questions/answers than there are good ones. Bad things get downvoted, good things only get upvoted if they're very good or interesting. downvoting is more important because it reduces the visibility of poor content. I don't see anything wrong with what you refer to as "mass downvoting".

Comment: I used to have a pretty healthy up/down vote ratio.  That's over and done with, downvotes have caught up half a year ago and now look back in the mirror.  All on questions.  I do not think that is *my* problem.  It is a community service.

Comment: related MSE discussion: [A badge that rewards “prophetic” downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134551/165773) _"Pale Horse Rider - When the Lamb opened the fourth seal, I heard the voice of the fourth living creature say, "Come and see!" I looked and there before me was a pale horse! Its rider was named Death, and Hades was following close behind him. They were given power over a fourth of the earth to kill by sword, famine and plague, and by the wild beasts of the earth."_

Comment: @Unihedron - *"I personally have a slightly high downvote to upvote ratio and I'm proud about it."* - that could also be an indication of the "I'm smarter than you" syndrome discussed in [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users). Remember, the site is for enthusiast programmers, too. Everyone won't have your mastery of a particular subject matter. (It seems to be a problem in some areas, like [tag:html] and [tag:javascript]).

Comment: You are free to vote in either direction. Just do it mindfully.

Comment: @eddie_cat Down-votes don't help clean up anything.  They're a signal, that's all.  If your down-votes don't come with helpful comments (assuming one isn't already there), a close vote (which has a reason for it built in), or a moderation flag (when warranted of course), you're doing nothing but signaling to other users your opinion.  If you really want to clean things up, edit posts and help people write better posts.

Comment: Related: [Jarrod Robertson's answer to "More effective closing/downvoting of junk questions to help with the signal-noise ratio"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252648/)

Comment: "but this kind of counteracts the point of anonymity." If you wish to remain anon don't comment, simple, let someone else who can deal with the problem do so

Comment: [RELATED 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198234/why-is-vote-count-exposed) & [RELATED 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220558/i-am-a-hater-because-people-do-not-understand-voting-patterns-properly)

Comment: @Brad not sure why you assumed I meant that you should *only* downvote. Of course if you are working to clean up the site you should use all tools available to you. Downvoting is one of those and even if you only do that, you are signaling to others that the post is low quality, which is a good thing to do.

Answer (score 21):

Your votes are yours to spend however you like, within reason. As long as you're voting based on content and not going to one person's profile and voting on a lot of questions and answers they've posted (whether up or down), you should be fine.

Having said that, I wonder if you might find fewer things worth downvoting if you set up some tags that interest you and used the [interesting tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) as your main page. You might already be doing this on your main account, but I find that this view gives me a better selection than drinking from the firehose of the [newest tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest).

Comment: Agreed. A high down-to-up ratio doesn't usually mean anything fishy, it just means someone is spending more of their time looking at bad questions, which is easy to do. If you're doing that on purpose, then great (and thanks from everyone!), but if not, it could lead to getting burned out on the site, so it may be worth looking for better ways to pick questions to look at.

Comment: @abarnert reddit gives badges to people who cast a lot of their votes from the /new page because it's such a wasteland. I don't think the problem on SO is nearly that bad yet, but there is a noticeable difference. But if anyone thinks SO/new is bad, they should view the site through the mod queue for a few days. ;)

Comment: Oh geez, it's even worse than the "interesting" tab after setting up relevant tags?

Comment: @tmyklebu Yes. The only thing you'll see different on the *new* tab is that it will highlight questions with your interesting tags. You still see every question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I meant themod queue.  I don't reeeally see much of a difference between the 'new' and 'interesting' tabs.  This gets me thinking, though, why aren't you guys using a text classifier for the 'interesting' tab instead of this tag system?  Each user already has a bunch of positive and negative examples (upvoted and downvoted questions).

Comment: @tmyklebu The "interesting" tab does use more than the tags you select. I know it looks at questions you've asked and answered, but I don't know if it uses votes.

Answer (score 10):

<sub>Disclaimer: This answer assumes "correct" use of votes, as they are planned</sub>

## Voting is good.

This counts for voting in general, which includes Upvoting and Downvoting.
Votes are all yours. How you spend them is yours to decide, and nobody should interfere with how you are voting. (excluding serial voting)

**Why is that?**

Voting on questions and answers is a mechanism to show accuracy / correctness of the post you vote on. (Meta is different, but alas..)

If you feel that a post deserves a downvote (and you got votes left), then by all means: **Do it!**
But keep in mind that the same counts for upvotes. When you think a post is well written and comprehensive, and thus worthy of an upvote: **Do it!**

As long as you don't misuse the power given to you for malicious purposes, **you can vote however you please**

**BUT:**

Votes are limited per day: You get 40 votes a day. This is a mechanism to prevent reddit-like inflations. It also limits the "value of reputation", but that's a different story.

### tl;dr;

Yes it is definitely okay to have more downvotes than upvotes.

Interesting trivia:
Eric Lippert, one of the Top [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) users has a Ratio u:D 1:1617 (as of now).
The more <s>reputation</s> *experience / knowledge* users gain, the more downvotes and the less upvotes they will use (at least in my experience).

Comment: Re. Eric Lippert's ratio, I think you mean U:D 1:1617.

Comment: Now I'm very curious what one post was worthy of an Eric Lippert upvote.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - there is discussion somewhere that the single upvote by Eric Lippert was mistake. Feel free to search...

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: I was trying to reverse a downvote after an edit and accidentally turned it into an upvote.

Comment: @Vogel612: I add plenty of value to these sites; upvoting is not one of the ways I choose to add that value. I am *extraordinarily* restrained in my downvoting; I have seen hundreds of thousands of questions and answers that thoroughly deserved downvoting. I try to only downvote questions and answers that are actively harming the world by their continued existence.

Comment: @EricLippert I never denied you are of (and adding) value to the site. I just said, that voting is a way to do so, and added some trivia about you, as an "extreme example". Whether you chose to abstain from voting on anything but dangerous q/a is not for me to decide ;) This answer just reflects my personal opinion. Whether you agree or not is nothing I can influence.

Comment: @Vogel612: I don't believe I said I disagreed with you. We may be in violent agreement! :-)

Comment: @EricLippert You could always edit the post again to remove the upvote, but it's a fun piece of trivia. :P

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly fine.

There is relatively small number of good and well written answers, and even smaller number of good questions on SO that truly deserve upvotes. There are many of "just ok" questions and answers which should just stay around 0. But then the rest are the once that deserve at least one downvote, especially on questions like "tried alot. write it form now".

So if one honestly decides to cast ~50 votes a day on random set of question and answers there will be more downvotes cast on initial versions of questions and answers than upvotes. This would be especially true if this votes need to be cast in short amount of time left to spend on SO.

Unfortunately most questions and many answers do not get improved at all so there is no reason for most voters to re-visit and remove downvotes (or possibly upvote the change). So rate stays.

---

Just kidding: I blame Jon Skeet for his fast and exceptionally good answers to skew bar for distinguishing "just ok" and "really good" answers :).