# Let interested 2k+ users also suggest edits

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

I just got the privilege to edit any question/answer at will, but I have minimal experience in editing questions/answers. Reputation is no way to tell how good an editor I am.

I would still like some of my edits to go to peer review queue. I have read this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290934/1180117), but still, I feel edit reviews like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29574894/revisions) help me learn what is a perfect edit.

Should something like a checkbox be added to indicate that I want my edit to be peer reviewed, regardless of my reputation?

Comment: Does this include 10K+ users? It'll be weird, if I check that checkbox, I might find myself reviewing myself :)

Comment: While this is an interesting suggestion, I would think that if you think you need a review of your edit, it's probably not an appropriate edit (changing more than should be changed). I would like to see some statistics about how suggested edits are reviewed. Your suggestion would actually make sense if it is true that many reviewers hit *improve edit* or *reject and edit*.

Comment: Are you implying that the outcome of a suggested edit review has anything to do with the quality of the edit? That's a good one.

Comment: @Maroun Users get access to the suggested edit queue when they reach 2k. There is no additional privilege for 10k. And of course, you shouldn't be able to review yourself.

Comment: @MarounMaroun As a regular user of the suggested edit queue with less than 10k rep, I can confirm that's not quite right  :)

Comment: @jdphenix thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: I agree with the idea. I've sometimes found myself in doubt whether my suggested edit was really a good one, especially when I had just hit >2k rep. In the end I guess the edits were good but it's nice to have some extra confirmation that I'm doing the right thing. ([Slightly related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287040/why-are-privileges-only-rep-dependent), you may find it interesting since you mentioned the reputation dependency)

Comment: I suspect this would mean that a sizable chunk of the edit queue is suddenly filled with edits by 2K users who are very conscientious but don't have enough confidence. If we had to review twice as many edits, but more than half of them were really good edits, it might make the reviewing process more pleasant, and then where would we be?

Comment: A pleasant reviewing process? What is this blasphemy?!

Comment: If you do not feel comfortable with your edit that you feel it needs to be reviewed, then it probably isn't an edit that's required.

Comment: I'm your +100 upvoter, enjoy. Just know that things happens really slow on this site if at all.

Comment: I think one good use-case for this idea would be when you want to expand an answer with an example of what was already covered. It wouldn't necessarily be approved by the original answerer and it shouldn't be automatically approved, but would be a good edit to suggest anyway.

Answer (score 85):

I like the idea!

Seeing as the suggested edits queue appears to clear out fast enough (to the point that it's often empty), this seems like a good idea.
It won't hurt >2k users to have that option, and <2k users won't see a difference...

Something like a checkbox next to the "Save edits" button should work just fine.

Some things to keep in mind:

- Don't allow edits on a person's *own* posts to enter the review queue.
  <sub>(I shouldn't be able to put edits on *this* post up for review)</sub>
- You shouldn't be able to review your own suggestions.

Comment: What would be the point? Did you see this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293599/let-interested-2k-users-also-suggest-edits#comment189923_293599 ? Perhaps a new queue, with no badges, may work, like a Review for Policy queue? Toss edits in there which are needed, but which you have concerns may be going "too far" with the OP's intent (I'm thinking of OPs who no longer attend the site). More like a Jury of peers. Majority to convict...

Comment: @BillWoodger: Do you have a good argument against this suggestion? If so, please post it as an answer. Why would this need a separate queue? I think we should take l4mpi's comment with a grain of salt.

Comment: Dissenting opinion duly posted. I wasn't saying this needed a separate queue, I was saying the only way using a queue would give any genuine quality feedback would be if it was not badge-driven, and the only reason to really submit such edits to a queue would be to get a community determination of the boundaries of possibility for an edit. And far from salt, I 100% agree with @I4mpi's comment if it means what I think it means :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus Reason for moving the accepted answer around was - 1) I had already started doing some of the things suggested there. Like had started looking into accepted/rejected edits by user NathanTuggy. 2) Out of earlier 15 edits I made, only 1 edit review helped. Others were just assurances. So at this point of time, I feel, only thing a suggested edit review will help, will be to provide an `assurance`. May be it is bad to not to trust the community to help here. But that is my thought now.

Comment: Would you get +2 rep if accepted?

Answer (score 46):

> TL;DR: reviewers ruin the day.

Before we delve into whether this is a good idea, we need to take a step back and see why people want this in the first place. There are two main categories of edits:

- **simple edits** which merely fix the formatting, spelling, grammar or punctuation of the post
- **substantive edits** which significantly reword the post based on subject matter experience

#### Substantive edits

If you're looking for advice on how to edit posts significantly while keeping the essence of what the user is really asking for, I'm afraid that your proposal won't give you the advice that you're looking for.

The vast majority of edits by <2k users come under the former umbrella and as a result, reviewers are only trained to handle the former case (most do not have experience in the subject matter of the specific question).

#### Simple edits

If on the other hand, you're just looking for experience with how to perform simple edits, it's a matter of having a relatively decent understanding of the English language.

Unfortunately, reviewers are (for the most part) okay at checking for proper use of formatting, but not all of them are able to judge well the spelling, grammar and wording of edits. We already have issues with "robo-reviewers" approving any post that isn't an obvious spam audit (yes, some even fail these too), so you probably won't get the advice and tips that you'd need.

Probably the best general advice I could give you is follow a few formatting guidelines when editing posts. A few off the top of my head are:

- Don't use `inline code spans` for anything other than code in sentences.
- **Bold** and *italic* should only be used when absolutely necessary.
- Don't add a space before semicolons, colons, question marks and periods (full stops).
- Code snippets should only be used for *runnable* JavaScript/HTML/CSS examples.
- Things like "thanks in advance" and "please help" are not necessary.

For anything else apart from that, it'd probably be best to ask some real people (perhaps in a chat room before doing it), who will be best able to judge your edit and provide feedback on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I'd add that "i" is not (yet) standard English for the first personal pronoun. It's "I" every time.

Comment: And also questions starting with "So" as if the asker is telling you a story, "So I am writing this program...".

Comment: I think that the last paragraph is the only particularly relevant part of this answer, and I don't think it's correct. You're suggesting that a would-be editor ask people to _review_ his edit; why do that in a chat room? Why not do that in the facility specifically designed to gather such reviews as efficiently and effectively as possible?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because that facility is designed to match suggested edits with users experienced in working of the site (high rep), not experts in the topic matter.  As this answer explains.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because I don't see any evidence that the review queue generates meaningful reviews of edits?

Answer (score 18):

The hope to be a good editor for the right reasons, rather than just having 2,000+ reputation, is commendable.

The probable flaw in the idea is the presumed expectation that the Edit Review queue has output related to "Review" rather than "Look at all my shiny badges and how fast I got them! Aren't I cool?" to help you achieve the aim of being a reliably good editor.

Although there is a substantial improvement to that queue with the "locking" of a review for a short period of time, it is still the case in my experience that the so-called Robo-reviewers are pretty effective at creating farce.

If concerned that your edit may not be up to scratch, do more research first.

Take the time that you'd spend editing for a week, and spend that itself looking at the top reviewers, and the reviews they have made.

Look first at a load of Accepts. Then look at a load of Rejects. Then look at a mix. If you can agree on the reject/accept say seven times out of 10, then you probably should be confident enough to do your edits without explicit "review". If you disagree too often, it probably means you need more research to get yourself "in synch" and then have the confidence to edit.

Remember also that there is a big difference in opinion between how exactly an edit should be made which is entirely unrelated to how an edit would be reviewed.

If you can make a post clearer, feel free to do so. Try to hit everything in that post that you can, with the emphasis on making it clearer. It is not a problem if someone else further improves the post later. If someone edits later and makes a mess of it, feel free to Rollback to your edit.

It's great that you want to do a better job of editing. I just don't think putting your edits through the Edit Review system would aid you as much as doing the research yourself would.

Comment: +1. The only reason I am not now marking this as accepted answer is since my initial thoughts having changed now in favor of this and could change tomorrow again. Will choose one as accepted as I stabilize. Regarding feature request, I feel, experts will take the right decision - what ever it is.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a great idea. Sometimes you are more confident about the quality of an edit than at other times. It would be really nice to explicitly let another pair(s) of eyes re-read your edit. After all, reviewers should also get to see a larger percentage of quality edits, to keep a sound frame of reference for the judgements they make.

For a peer review (which is what you're after I presume) to make sense for the author of the edit as well, he should receive also qualified positive feedback. This is currently not possible, given the current review queue mechanics. (I made a suggestion that goes a step in that direction here: [Can we make approving suggested edits harder?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292368/1025391) - a small step admittedly.)