# put own edit (of someone else's Q or A) up for review despite 'edit' priviledge

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, privileges

I recently gained the ['edit' privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) on Stack Overflow. Often, when editing others' questions or answers, I'm sure of what I'm doing and thus it's nice that my changes are now applied immediately.

Sometimes, however, I'd still like to simply *suggest* an edit and would like it to be peer reviewed before it is applied. In some of these cases, leaving a comment for the original author instead of doing the editing myself is an option, but in some cases, showing the changes I'd want to suggest themselves (and explaining only their *reason* in the edit comment) would be much more efficient than explaining *what* changes I suggest.

Having the 'edit' privilege, can I opt an edit I make to go to the edit suggestions queue instead of being applied immediately? If not, would an option like this be beneficial or put undue load on the suggested edits queue?

Comment: Just submit the edit, if the OP disagrees with the edit they can roll it back.

Comment: at main site (not on meta), you can simply open post in logged out (aka "private", "incognito") mode, click "improve this question/answer" link and submit edit suggestion as anonymous user

Comment: In addition to @TinyGiant suggestion - consider to add comment like "I've edited your post to xxxxxx, please rollback if it does not match your intention/consider clarifying YYYY if rolled back". Such comment (assuming OP is actually active on site) likely eliminates chance of "$#$#$ you've touched my post" comments and generally make more positive impression. (Makes sure also to read second [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293631/477420) in duplicate - it is unlikely to get type of review you are looking for)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov good idea about the comment. That matches well with what the workflow on http://stackoverflow.com/review/helper encourages editors to do. And yes, I've already read (and upvoted) answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293631/477420 when agreeing to close my question as duplicate. Made me change my point of view.