# What to do if not sure about an own edit as a 2k+ user?

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently earned the privilege of having my edits applied without going through the review queues. While I'm generally happy about this, I just came across a situation where I wanted to change the title of a question to match the question a lot better.

I was sure that the change would be at least a minor improvement, however, there might be even better options. So I would have loved to have my changes reviewed before making them. For now, I didn't make the change.

What is the best way to handle my situation? Don't make the change? Apply it and let the OP (or others) revert it if it turns out not that good?

**Edit/Clarification**: Seeing that this question was marked as a duplicate of [Let interested 2k+ users also suggest edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293599), let me explain the difference: My question (since my last edit) is about what to do as long as that feature doesn't exist. From the answers there, I couldn't find any hint on what to do in that situation. The closest thing is in this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293631/3198247 Which I would basically read as "You aren't going to get the feedback you want anyways, *so just use your own judgement*", with the italic part being what I infer. If so, should I lead on the side of caution and don't make the edit, or make and rely on others reverting it should it turn out bad?

Comment: To the downvoters after the clarification: care to explain why this is still a duplicate/bad question?

Comment: You'll learn by doing and making mistakes.  By improving the site, you will be improving your own ability and confidence to improve the site.  *I didn't DV, but it really still is a dupe.  Advice and recommendations about what you should specifically do **can** be found within the answers and comments.*

Comment: It's not a dupe. A question asking "what to do" cannot possibly be a duplicate of a feature request.

Comment: Well, you *can* always ask on meta or in chat. Try not to do it often, and make sure you ask in the right room at the right time following local conventions.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307838/put-own-edit-of-someone-elses-q-or-a-up-for-review-despite-edit-priviledge#comment257261_307838

Answer (score 2):

If you have doubts that its the right thing to do, don't make an edit. Generally speaking you need to be able to trust your own judgement in determining what you should and should not edit. With the growing responsibility, ideally, you also grow as a person and learn to better make these calls.