# Should edits to off-tag answers be peer reviewed?

Tags: discussion, edits

When you edit an answer, if you have more than a certain amount of reputation, the edit is automatically approved.

So when I edited a Python answer it didn't need to be peer reviewed, even though I'm not a Python expert:

[Read a file in reverse order using python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23646049/50552)

Would it be a good idea to make off-tag edits subject to peer review?  Either by automatically detecting you're not an expert based on tag, or by adding a checkbox for it.

Comment: Depends where you stand.  Are you volunteering to do all the extra reviewing?

Comment: Related [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293599/let-interested-2k-users-also-suggest-edits).

Answer (score 4):

The rep limit is to give you experience in the site so you know what edits are allowed and what are not. I.e. that code edits are [not something that you should be doing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Given that you should be restricting edits to grammar/spelling issues it does not require expertise in a tag to do that.

If you feel an answer is incorrect, leave a comment and/or downvote it or if you feel it necessary, add your own answer.