# Require X approved suggested edits before gaining Edit privilege

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Prompted by this [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298501/offer-more-help-to-authors-of-bad-edits?cb=1), I've read up on the [Edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (from here on referred to as `sudo edit`).

I understand this is a privilege that is earned by gaining 2,000 reputation on the site. As far as I can see, that is the only requirement - there doesn't seem to be any restrictions on where you get that rep from. For instance, I got mine mostly through answers and a few questions - I think I may have made one suggested edit before gaining this privilege which allows me to edit anything, without peer review.

I've done my best to make edits that will be helpful to others and in-keeping with the ethos of SO, but the problem is I never had to learn to edit other's content. I feel this is a skill all of its own.

Assuming I'm right about there being no other restrictions on this privilege, I feel me and others like me would benefit if they had to suggest some *good* edits & have them approved before being handed the `sudo edit` hammer.

This would allow us to learn before potentially making a mess of other's perfectly good posts.

I'm not sure if the suggested edits review queue is a problem or not, admittedly I don't contribute much there - if it is, this may add traffic but reduce bad `sudo edits` in the long run.

> Should SO require a certain number of approved suggested edits before
>   the Edit privilege can be earned?

Please note - I'm not trying to suggest that there are roving bands of 2K users rampantly defiling posts left and right; rather this is more focussed on introducing a learning curve for edits, rather than allowing users who may have no idea how to edit a post edit anything.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287040/why-are-privileges-only-rep-dependent

Comment: Are you implying that the result of a suggested edit review has anything to do with the quality of the edit? I'm all for people learning how to edit, but reviews are not exactly the right tool for this. I personally didn't suggest many edits before reaching 2k (and still don't edit all that much), but I'm aware of the rules and guidelines due to lurking a lot. Also, there are significant differences between a suggested edit and a 2k edit due to the fact that a 2k edit does not need to be reviewed; people couldn't learn those differences from reviews anyways.

Comment: @l4mpi I think having a few edits rejected or accepted with reasons supplied may help with learning the ropes in that regard - but I'm not saying that rejected or accepted edits are always correct. I agree it isn't the right tool but there isn't another tool available (that I know of) that will help someone learn how to make good edits. Can you suggest a better one?

Comment: I would suggest that this should not be needed at all. If there are people who reach 2k and then continue to flood the site with crap edits, they can be talked to and/or suspended. And the best way to learn anything about any community ever is of course to lurk and see what the community thinks is good or bad behaviour.

Comment: @l4mpi I agree that lurking can help you figure out how a community operates - but currently there is nothing to make you do that or suggest it as a way to learn good editing practices. a reading list may help that could be shown to users when they gain the editing privilege? the point being, I'd rather be able to bring something to the party than turn up at four or five of them while forgetting a bottle of wine until I learn the hard way what is expected.

Comment: A user can get to 2K and above without ever visiting meta - It wasn't until relatively recently I started reading it myself. I want to learn good editing skills, preferably before I contribute to wasting reviewer's time. I think there should be a way to do that.

Comment: But even with no experience of edits, a user at 2k rep has clearly been around the site a lot and seen their share of questions and answers, the good and the bad. They know what they should look like, even if they don't know the finer points of editing itself.

Comment: I think this is making a problem out of something which is not even manifested in any way yet, other than a fear of failure. You fear that you will do damage to someone else's question - really? I'm pretty sure you are far better than that and you'll do edits when you're reasonably sure about it. Your 2k rep proves that you're better than that. And even when you 'derp' it up in a moment of brain-meltdown, I do believe your edits aren't as permanent as you think they are; they can be rolled back, including by the person who wrote the question.

Comment: Way to many bad edits are approved for this to be of any value.

Comment: @joew thats interesting. I think there could be a good way to educate people to make good edits. You think there are too many bad edits being approved. Maybe this is the other side of the same coin? My idea might not be the right way but i think there is something we could do. Education may help the reviewers to stop approving so many bad edits, and for the users to stop submitting them.

Comment: The problem isn't the lack of education but rather the fact that some reviewers are just chugging through the queue approving everything and grinding for the review queue badges.

Comment: With exactly the opposite situation from the asker, I [would _love_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252989/241211) to be able to make edits without jamming up the review queue.

Comment: Related (and rejected): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149187/voluntary-suggested-edit-for-users-with-edit-privileges

Comment: Related (and still open): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298174/let-me-comment-on-reviews-and-notify-the-reviewers

Comment: *I think I may have made one suggested edit before gaining this privilege*
– You made
[*eight (8) suggestions*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846480?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).
They all got approved. 

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are certainly advantages to a system that gives you less oversight for specific tasks as you demonstrate more proficiency in performing those tasks. If Stack Overflow had been designed with suggested edits in place from day one, it is plausible that this is the system that would have been used.

However, there are downsides to this as well, and they're particularly harsh when added after-the-fact:

- It creates a positive feedback loop. If reviewers lean a certain direction slightly, the next wave of editors will lean that direction greatly.
- At this point, a great number of editors have *never* suggested an edit, instead earning the privilege via reputation alone. Changing the rules part-way through is never something to be done lightly.
- It ignores the value of your other contributions to the site.

You've earned a powerful privilege that you're unsure of how to use effectively, and... It scares you a bit. **Great!** That's a sign that you value work that others have put into this site, and recognize how carelessness on your part could hurt them. You recognize this because **you** put a fair bit of work in. You view the site in an entirely different way than someone new would; you're part of the group, and are aware that it lives and can be hurt.

This is the meaning of Reputation. The system trusts you because you've given it reason to believe you can be trusted. You've given of yourself, and received trust in return. If you were to abuse that trust, it might be taken from you - but you wouldn't knowingly do so.

The value of experienced-based privileges is the tendency of people to keep doing in the future what they've done in the past. The value of trust-based privileges is the reluctance of people to lose the respect of their peers. Both have flaws, but Stack Overflow's trust-based system has proven to be extremely flexible and light-weight, which was (and still is) critical for operating at the scale needed. Experiments in experienced-based systems within Stack Overflow have had mixed success.

Comment: As a partial solution, maybe allow `sudo edit` at a certain rep level (1k estimated) *if* the user had made a certain number of approved edits (and not tag edits, probably), and if that user got 2k, remove the requirement of approved edit at all. None got hurt, several people can now edit questions without approval, having already displayed they can do good edits.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Shog's excellent point, one of the main reasons reputation is linked to the ability to make edits unilaterally is that reputation is an effective stand-in for experience.  You've been on the site long enough to gain 2000 reputation, that means:

1. You clearly know (to some extent) how to make posts that the community deems valuable.
2. You've probably read a decent number of questions and answers, and as such have some idea of what the community considers a good question.

As such, you probably know enough to make edits to correct posts to community standards.  It's not a guarantee, but in the scheme of things it's probably better to have more people making edits than less; we have a lot of content that needs editing, after all.

In addition, there's relatively little risk involved here.  If a 2k user starts making edits that are inappropriate, there are thousands upon thousands of other 2k users who can correct them - and odds are, will.  In the rare case that a 2k user is making edits no other 2k users can see, there's always the moderator flag, plus the original poster can of course always correct any edit to their posts.

Comment: I've earned 2K rep after being only 10 days on the site (roughly 200 per day, check my rep history). Now I'm 10K and have many privileges, but I'm still only 2 months here. The fact that I know well some programming topics and can write many upvoted answers does not mean that I learned all the SO rules so quickly. I tried my best to read FAQs/help/meta, but probably sometimes my edits or moderation decisions were not very well. Probably it would be better to provide editing privileges no earlier than one month (or even later) after registration.