# Can't fix up incorrect upvote?

Tags: bug, questions

I can't change my vote on an answer (to someone else's question).

I voted a question up accidentally but found that pushing the down arrow after that would not let me remove my vote.

After returning to my work it struck me some 10-15 minutes later that perhaps I had to "unpress" the up arrow next to the offending question to cancel my upvote. And lo and behold, it really is that counterintuitive.

Apparently though I was too slow so now I can't correct the mistake and have forever recommended a workaround to a problem that has better solutions listed.

Three questions:

1 - What purpose could it serve for me to both up- and down-vote a question? How would that even work?

2 - What am I supposed to do now? Upvote everything else twice?

3 - How can it serve anyone's purpose to embed mistaken votes in stone?

Note: These are rhetorical questions in the hope that someone rethinks how things work. I already know that the answers to all of the above will be "because we are Stack Overflow and we are legion and by the way you spelt something wrong in your question".

Comment: Simple solution: [Don't lose your keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/305827). :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry - we all make mistakes (even [Eric Lippert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270750/4751173)). With millions of questions, something like this is bound to happen.

1. You can't - a downvote would cancel an earlier upvote, and vice versa.
2. You can cancel your upvote if the question is edited in the future. Even if you edit it yourself, but your edit must improve the question (otherwise, it will be rejected). If you improve the question enough, you might even want to consider leaving your upvote.
3. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265858/can-we-remove-vote-lock-in/291292#291292).

Comment: Thanks. So are you telling me that I could get a notification in the future and I'd have 10 minutes to fix the vote or it would be locked again?