# What is this edit about?

Tags: support, edits, specific-edit

Recently I noticed an edit on my post here ([Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73534113/2)):

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73534113/revisions

Looking at the side-by-side I'm having trouble understanding what changed.  There is a dash that's highlighted but in both cases it's still a dash. Can someone help clarify what changed about the dash character here and *why*? Also, I thought we have to update at least X amount of characters - how is an edit like this even possible?

Comment: The edit was made by a 2k user so they can bypass the min size for an edit

Comment: Ok - I didn't know about that privilege, thanks.  Still scratching my head about the edit itself.

Comment: Most likely incorrect (may depend on the style guide). *[The Chicago Manual of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style)* 6.78: *"The principal use of the en dash is to connect numbers, and less often, words."*. It would be nice with [an actual edit summary](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73534113/revisions).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Changed the hyphen to [an en-dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html).  Makes me roll my eyes about that edit.  Not the kind of edit you should make, like - ever, just because it's damn near indistinguishable from a regular hyphen.
2. The editor has over 173K rep.  You can make edits without needing to go through a queue starting at 2K rep, so this would naturally bypass the queue.

Comment: So tempted to edit your hyphen now...

Comment: If you do it I swear to God—

Comment: Weird.. upon [further reading](https://www.scribbr.com/language-rules/dashes/) it appears that this is actually not the correct usage of an en-dash.  Maybe should be an em-dash but um...

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue: Yeah it should be, if we were being correct.  But it's like...just so irrelevant to the flow of the post...

Comment: Usually such "invisible" edits are done to undo a vote... Which I'm tempted to do here just to do that :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  I'm sure cleaning up the italics would have made for a *much* better edit than some silly dash.

Comment: @Makoto I'd say it would make much *worse* edit if the sole purpose is unlocking the vote.... But yes, ideally if one makes an edit than the post should become better after the edit rather staying visually identical... Which I guess is why Eric Lippert had one upvote - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270746/high-downvote-to-upvote-ratio-not-serial-downvoting/270750#comment92368_270750 as probably he did not want to edit the post second time and making a null-change like en-dash...

Comment: From *[The Chicago Manual of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style)* 6.76: *"Though many readers may not notice the difference—especially between an en dash and a hyphen—correct use of the different types is a sign of editorial precision and care."*

Comment: In any case, it wasn't complete. [A later revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73534113/revisions) fixed *"and existing"*.